# Python and Hadoop - fetch and write data directly to hdfs using python?

Tags: python, hadoop

I want to fetch the data daily from yahoo/google finance, related to stock's eod prices. These prices should be directly stored in HDFS in file.

I can later make external table on top of it (using HIVE) and use for further analysis.

So, I am not looking for basic map-reduce, since I don't have any input file as such.
Are there any connectors available in python, which can write data in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

Start with dumping your data in a local file. Then find a way to upload the file to HDFS.

- If you are running your job on an "edge node" (i.e. a Linux box that
  is not part of the cluster but has all the Hadoop clients installed
  and configured), then you have the good old HDFS command-line
  interface

> `hdfs dfs -put  data.txt  /user/johndoe/some/hdfs/dir/`

- If you are running your job anywhere else, use an HTTP library (or    good old `curl` command line) to connect to the HDFS REST service -- could be [either    webHDFS or httpFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033729/webhdfs-vs-httpfs) depending on the way the cluster has been set up -- and upload the file with a *PUT* request

> `http://namenode:port/webhdfs/v1/user/johndoe/some/hdfs/dir/data.txt?op=CREATE&overwrite=false`
>
> *(and the content of "data.txt" as payload, of course)*

Comment: BTW: when using a REST service against a HA cluster, you must call each NameNode until you find the active one.

Comment: BTW, when unsing a REST service against a secure cluster, you must set up a Kerberos SPNEGO authentification - and optionally store the Hadoop *delegation token* for the duration of the session.